# flutter how can i rebuild my widget when api change?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have some api like this :

```
 "users" : {
     "userId": 1,
     "id": 2,
     "title": "book",
     "body": "this book is good "
  },
```

and fetch data great and pass to text widget :

```
Text(users['body']);
```

but i want to rebuild text widget when api change (like this => **"body" : "this book is bad"**) .

how can i do that without using any timer.

Thank you friends (:

Comment: Only websocket-like events can trigger changes for you to listen. Regular API calls use a "pull" (GET) logic and even if you change something, your client app will never know about it.

Comment: you're right , do u have any sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to do this. You either need your API to have a system that notifies you when there are changes or use a timer.

For example if you are using Firebase database, you have access to a listener for when the data change which is something like this:

```
var subscription = FirebaseDatabase.instance
                   .reference()
                   .child('messages')
                   .onXxx
                   .listen((event) {
                       // process event and update your UI here
                    });
```

Another option would be implementing push notifications in your API and listen for them in your app. So when any change is done in the api, a push notification, using FCM, is sent to your app to notify it that there is a change. In your app you listen for it and rebuild your ui accordingly.

The last option is the Timer which is fairly straight forward.

```
@override
 void initState() {
   getFixture();
   _timer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 30), 
   (_) => getYourDatafromAPI());
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   _timer.cancel();
   super.dispose();
 }
```

As an alternative, you might be interested in using Streams. This works similarly to a timer. You can check a working example of Streams from Json [here](https://dev.to/iiits-iota/using-stream-builder-in-flutter-3hkc)

Comment: Thank you dear friend , I will test .

Comment: Glad to help. If this works for you please select this as an answer.